# How do I fix my jumping and movement glitchy (slow motion)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

when I sprint and jump around my world, my movement is quite choppy / laggy, and it's not at all smooth. It slows down in the middle of the jump, and seems to speed up after I've landed.

I'm playing Java 1.15.2, with OptiFine 1.15.2 HD U G1 pre9, however the problem persists even if i play without Optifine.

I have tried playing with and without custom JVM arguments, but the issue remains.

Computer Specs:

- Intel Core i5 - 2.5 GHz
- 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 RAM
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

[Video of the Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P39WRFIDB84&feature=emb_title)

Comment: If I see it correctly, it seems a little bit like you're hitting something in mid-air and getting stopped by it for a short moment, but then go forwards again. It only seems to happen on some jumps and then usually in the middle of the jump. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from one instance, which might be the recording more than your gameplay, this is exactly what it looks like, when moving and jumping around. This is just perspective, because you are changing your relative position on two separate axes.

In any case your game is running smoothly and your movement is correct. I don't know if changing the field of view (FOV) may help with this perspective.

I couldn't find any stuttering, lagging, chopping or similar in your linked video.